# How to kill Elixir process after timeout

Tags: elixir

How can I launch an Elixir process and then kill it after a timeout? I've got code like this:

```
defmodule OperationsManager do
  def run_operation do
    spawn fn -> 
      # long operation 
    end
  end
end
```

The inner operation may last too long to wait for its end, so I need to kill the process from manager. How can I do it?

EDIT:

Important detail: I need to spawn several operations and all of them should have individual timeout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would take a look at the Elixir [Task module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Task.html).

You can handle a single task using `Task.yield` or multiple tasks `Task.yield_many` for a given interval although `Task.yield` seems closer to what you might need.
Yield returns `{:ok, result}` (sucessful returns), `{:exit, reason}` (Task crashed) or `:nil` (timeout interval surpassed).
You can also consider putting the Task in a supervision tree.

The following code is based on elixir 1.2.1.

```
defmodule OperationsManager do
  def run_operation() do

    task1 = Task.async(fn() -> operation("task 1", 1) end)
    result = Task.yield(task1, 5000)
    process_task(task1, result)

    task2 = Task.async(fn() -> operation("task 2", 2) end)
    task4 = Task.async(fn() -> operation("task 4", 4) end)
    task6 = Task.async(fn() -> operation("task 6", 6) end)
    task8 = Task.async(fn() -> operation("task 8", 8) end)

    results = Task.yield_many([task2, task4, task6, task8], 7000)
    for {task, res} <- results do
      process_task(task, res)
    end

  end

  def process_task(task, res) do
    case res do
      :nil ->
        IO.write("shutting down timed out task: ")
        IO.inspect(task)
        Task.shutdown(task, :brutal_kill)
      {:ok, task_number} ->
        IO.puts("#{task_number} is complete")
      {:exit, _reason} ->
        # some logic when the task terminates
    end
  end

  def operation(task_number, timeout) do
    :timer.sleep(timeout * 1000)
    task_number
  end

end


OperationsManager.run_operation()
```

Comment: I'm just starting to learn Elixir, so maybe I'll have enough questions to increase you reputation at SO even higher :)

Answer (score 13):

Just for completeness: the erlang `:timer` module has a function [`kill_after`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#kill_after-1) that will forcefully kill the process after the time has elapsed.

```
# Kill the current process after 2 seconds 
:timer.kill_after(:timer.seconds(2))

# Kill pid after 2 minutes
:timer.kill_after(:timer.minutes(2), pid)
```

Comment: That should be the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You could use sending messages between processes to manage various cases, for example:

```
parent_pid = self()
spawn_pid = spawn fn -> 
  # some code...
  # :timer.sleep(1_500)
  send(parent_pid, {:done, self()})
end
# wait a result from spawned proccess
receive do
  {:done, pid} -> "Got :done from #{inspect pid}"
after # 1s timeout
  1_000 -> Process.exit(spawn_pid, :kill)
end
# ensure that spawned process is finished or killed
Process.alive?(spawn_pid) # => false
```

Comment: But it's suitable only when there is only one operation, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean? Each spawned operation will return a PID. So you can do with them anything that you want.

Comment: I mean, if I spawn two operations at different times, how will `receive` construction distinguish timeout for one operations from timeout for another? But maybe I miss some point.

Comment: It's too big topic for a comment. So I recommend to read this article: http://theerlangelist.com/article/beyond_taskasync